# No money on account after migrating to new Admob

Tags: admob

Admob migrated to a newer version some days ago. They transfered my apps successfully, but it seems that I have to restart from 0,00 bucks. I had about 15$ in my old Admob. How can I transfer it to the new one, or will it be lost? Payout limit is 75$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See here "What happens to the funds in my old account":

You can request a refund of your legacy AdMob account balance. This refund request is for advertisers only. If you're inquiring about earnings from your legacy AdMob account, they'll be paid as normal through the regular payment cycle. New earnings will accrue in the new system and will be paid out via the payment method specified in the new interface.

https://support.google.com/admob/v2/faq/3108470?hl=en&ref_topic=3338971&rd=1#3131214

Comment: what if you switch your apps to the new admob, and you haven't hit the payment threshold with the old admob, any idea where that remaining balance goes?

Comment: Hi @stu it'll be paid normally, mentioned in the link mentioned by Apostolos. "  ... AdMob account will be paid as normal through the regular payment cycle, even if it has not met the payment threshold."

Comment: I also have same issue but as per them it will be credited in new account after October but still nothing happen my $20 is not fulfill any threshold any idea to whom i can contact?

Comment: @itin Same problem here too. Did you manage to get your money?

Comment: Not yet but i have mailed them (form is given in the help of admob what "happen to my legacy payment") and i got the response that they will credit that amount in new admob.